# SecurityError: fileWriteResource when I try to delete file

Tags: actionscript-3, file-io

After I receive files via ftp and process them I try to delete, however the FB throws this error: SecurityError: fileWriteResource.

I'm still debugging; my app works for Android and Desktop.
Follows the code:

```
var xmlFile : File = new File();
if(app == 'ANDROID'){
    xmlFile = new File('/mnt/sdcard/SAG/' + dbPath); // PARA ANDROID 
    if(xmlFile.exists ){
        xmlFile.deleteFile();                       
    }
}else if(app == 'DESKTOP'){
    //app == DESKTOP
    xmlFile = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(arquivos.source[itemIndex].name);
    if(xmlFile.exists ){
        xmlFile.deleteFile();//the file exists, but don´t delete because a error
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you process them ? Do you open them via a FileStream ? If yes, do you close the stream before deleting the file? Have you tried async deletion ?

Comment: i tried async deletion, but not work, the stream is already closed too... thanks for response!